# Is this an actual source?

Tags: discussion

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/26362/6901 this person cites a source which is a *method* that a search engine could use to rank pages, but doesn't actually prove that a search engine actually uses that method. Is than an acceptable source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a source for the guess("My guess is...") in the response, so sure it's acceptable *in that context*. But it shouldn't be assumed to apply any further than that unless an engineer from each of the major engines(since asker didn't specify) steps in and says, "Yep, that's what we do."

It's an interesting bit of theoretical information, but probably of limited value as an actual answer to the question, if you want to be strict about the "practical, actual problems" bit of the StackExchange FAQs. (If the questions have to be practical, then presumably so do the answers.) I'd actually argue that the answer is weak based on its near-complete unprovability, rather than whether the citation's any good.

[It's not a great question in the first place, really, and I'm almost certain there's at least a few prior dupes of it.]